# Angular - Stop observable timer on search bar input

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

Currently I have an orders list component where I display a bunch of orders. These orders are requested from an API and are updated in a interval of 2 minutes, like so:

```
this.subscription = timer(0, 120 * 1000).subscribe(() => {
    this.getInitialPendingTabOrders();
    this.getInitialDeliveredTabOrders();
    this.getInitialCancelledTabOrders();
});
```

This works great. However, I also have a search bar implemented where I can filter through different orders. What I want is for this auto-update functionality in the code above to **not** be applied when a search is active (right now search results are reset when the subscription triggers).

Is there a way for me to stop the subscription momentarily when I'm in the search bar context?

Also, it's worth noting the search bar is a child component of the orders component.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @eko `takeWhile` kills the stream. Not what OP is asking for.

Comment: "worth noting the search bar is a child component of the orders component"...Rachid's answer still applies but you have to get the `isSeachActive` from the child. Normal ways of doing this apply

Comment: @AndrewAllen you're right 

Comment: Thanks for the input guys. @RachidOussanaa answer is indeed working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the easiest way I think of is to filter out the emissions of the timer when your search is active:

```
this.subscription = timer(0, 120 * 1000).pipe(filter(() => isSearchActive )).subscribe(() => {
    this.getInitialPendingTabOrders();
    this.getInitialDeliveredTabOrders();
    this.getInitialCancelledTabOrders();
});
```

and in your parent component you could have

```
<child-search (searchActive)="isSearchActive = true" ></child-search>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The search bar is a child component of the orders component. Would this still work if I emit a boolean event to the parent when the search is active?

Comment: yes it would still work, just have the emited boolean from the child update the `isSearchActive` in your parent component

Comment: i updated the answer to include the template